# Resetting a timer within a modular function seems to cause timer not to fire. Why doesn't the setTimeout work?

Tags: javascript, timer

Code Example:

```
define(function() {
    var self = this,
        saveTimer = null,
        saveFunction = null,
        timer_sleep = 0;

    self.initAutoSave = function initAutoSave(saveMethod, duration) {
        timer_sleep = duration;

        saveFunction = function saveFunction() {
            if (saveMethod) {
                saveMethod();
            }
        }

        saveTimer = window.setTimeout(saveFunction, timer_sleep);
    }

    self.resetAutoSave = function resetAutoSave() {
        window.clearTimeout(saveTimer);

        saveTimer = window.setTimeout(saveFunction, timer_sleep);
    }

    return self;
});
```

The module above is used to setup an autosave method. What I have noticed is that initially the method is called. Later however when I call reset the method is no longer called.

I have spent some time researching this and can find no reason why a setTimeout would suddenly cease to fire after having the timer cleared and reset.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why not call `initAutoSave` method (instead of `setTimeout`) inside `resetAutoSave`?

Comment: could you add a fiddle?

Comment: @hindmost that would be a little redundant initializing variables to the same values just to run the one line I'm already running wouldn't it?

Comment: @think win win I can pull it out of the module and build it into a fiddle, but that defeats the purpose of the question. The issue I'm experiencing would require the module to be in a separate file and be loaded with requirejs. I'm not sure how to do that with Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason for this is due to the fact that the function needs to be passed into the reset so when the timer is reinitialized it can have a reference to the function like so:

```
    self.resetAutoSave = function resetAutoSave(saveMethod) {
    window.clearTimeout(saveTimer);
    saveTimer = null;
    saveFunction = null;

    saveFunction = function saveFunction() {
        if (saveMethod) {
            saveMethod();
        }
    }

    saveTimer = window.setTimeout(saveFunction, timer_sleep);
}
```